# Motorboat rental in Lazio, Italy

Tags: budget, italy, rental

I am wondering, does anyone know where and how to get a reasonably priced motorboat rental?

I would like to find a motorboat between 30-40 HP (so no license is needed) at Gaeta / Anzio / Formia / around for a reasonable price (60 - 120 EUR / day).

From what I have seen so far everything is terribly overpriced, asking for as much as 200 EUR (and ALREADY in June).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Renting a motorboat is quite expensive here. One of the best deal I managed to found that barely meets your criteria is in [Gaeta](http://www.martinpescatore.com/partner/index_MagaNoleggio.shtm). The site is quite shitty and it's Italian only so here is what it says:

Gommone "Joker Boat" 5.5 mt, renting from 8:30 to 18:30. Prices are without fuel:

- May - June: 120 €
- July: 130 €
- August: 140 €
- September 120 €

You better contact them to make sure these informatins are not outdate!

Here are the contact informations: 
Maga' Noleggio - barche e gommoni con e senza patente nautica
Via Lungomare Caboto - Gaeta
Cell. 349.0943062
E-mail: venom19751975@yahoo.it

Comment: well, my Italian is bad but " quando a bordo dell'unita' sia installato un motore avente una cilindrata superiore a ..." talks clearly about a motor volume limits and CV / HP limits.

Comment: I'm sure you read my explanation of point b)

Comment: sure, but I know you can borrow any "gommone" no matter how big if its combined engine power is below 40HP and that's what I am interested in. Any suggestions for a good deal?

Comment: dang, I'm deeply sorry, because, for some reason, I thought you were interested in jetski. I'm gonna update the answer now.

Comment: edited, check it out